# Using Bellman Ford to detect cycles with product exceeding threshold

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, bellman-ford

[Bellman Ford](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-23-bellman-ford-algorithm/) is used to detect negative weighted cycles in a graph. I would like to know how I can use it to detect cycles which **exceeds** a certain threshold instead.

Example:

```
               --------->
               ^        |1
       0.5     | <------v
1 -----------> 2 
^             |
|4            |1
|     2       v
4<------------3
```

This graph has 2 cycles. One with the product = 1 and the other with the product = 4. If the threshold = 1, the algorithm should output true, since there is 1 cycle with a product > 1.

Comment: Are you referring only to **simple cycles**? Because, by repeating a cycle with positive weight, you can exceed any positive threshold.

Comment: yes! You traverse the cycle once. That is the "product of the cycle" @amit

Comment: Isn’t that what Dijkstra’s is for? At least in this case since you have no negative cycles.

Comment: @Sailanarmo Dijkstra is for finding the shortest path between one node and the others/a destination node. How would that help here?

Comment: @User12547645 you can modify Dijkstra’s algorithm to keep track of any weights that exceed the threshold that you described.

Comment: One straight forward way of doing this is to start a DFS from a vertex and book-keep the weight that you have encountered so far. If you have a Back edge during the DFS, then it is a cycle. Check if it is greater than the threshold, and print it.

Comment: @Raghav That does not work (unless you explore every path in the DFS, and this takes exponential time), if for example you have (a,b,1),(b,c,5),(a,c,2) - there is no guarantee (a,c,2) will be used, and you'll think path to (a,c) costs 5, which in fact it could cost less. (As shown below, there is no known way to do it in polynomial time).

Comment: @amit, The problem statement only asks for the product of the weights of the edges that form a cycle. So a DFS would find the cycle if it is present and all you need to do is just a product of the weights of the edges.  `(a,b,1),(b,c,5),(a,c,2)` doesn't have any cycle. If there was an additional edge, say `(c,a,3)`, then the graph would have a cycle, with weights (1,5,3) so the product would turn out to be 15. We need not consider about the edge `(a,c,2)`. Also the problem doesn't want the lowest cost path.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to detect a **simple** cycle with weight that exceeds some threshold (otherwise, you can repeat any positive weight>1 cycle enough times to exceed any positive threshold).

Unfortunately, that problem is [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

A simple reduction from the [Hamiltonian cycle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem):

Given an instance `G=(V,E)` of Hamiltonian cycle problem, keep the same graph `G`, with `w(e) = 2` for any edge, and send it to the problem with threshold `2^|V|-1`.

If there is any cycle with weight bigger than `2^|V|-1, then it has more than`|V|-1` edges, so this cycle is hamiltonian, and if there is a hamiltonian cycle, the algorithm will find that there is a cycle of weight 2*2*...*2> 2^|V|-1.

Since Hamiltonian Cycle is Np-Complete, and we found polynomial reduction from it to this problem, this problem is NP-Hard, and there is no known polynomial solution to it.

---

tl;dr: to use Bellman Ford to solve this problem, is far from trivial, and if possible, will require modifying the graph to be exponential in size of the original graph (Assuming P!=NP)

Comment: to much theoretical CS right there :D Still thanks for the insight.

Comment: @User12547645 Theoretical cs becomes practical when you understand what you ask for cannot be done :|

Comment: Agreed. It can be very helpful, indeed. My other thought was to implement it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394471/calculate-product-of-weights-in-circle-graph?noredirect=1#comment87812954_50394471

Comment: It seems like the people who answered here assume that it can be done (maybe I did not describe the task well in this post).

Comment: Wait, I might have misunderstood you. I now see you asked for product, not sum. My answer assumes regular weight, which is sum. I need to rethink it over (will delete answer in few minutes).

Comment: Thank you! I would really like to know how to implement it. I spend quite some time on it, but unfortunatly my implementation seems to be floored.

Comment: @User12547645 Actually, unless the weights are in [0,1] I don't think it makes much change.
You can simply transform the problem easily to sum problem by setting threshold'=log(threshold), and for each weight, weight'=log(weight). Then, it's back to the same problem. (The reduction will be setting 2 to each weight, and seeing if there is a path that exceeds `2^|V|-1`. This is still polynomial reduction, and proves NP Hardness. Will update answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Solution to the problem**

This solution is working, whenever the threshold is equal to 1.

**tl;dr** Change weights of edges, by applying logarithm and use Floyd-Warshal to detect negative cycles, which will occur, if the product of the original weights of a cycle is greater than 1.

**long answer**. 
Floyd-Warshal can be used for APSP, as well as detecting [negative cycles in a graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detecting-negative-cycle-using-floyd-warshall/). To make this problem a problem, were the solution involves finding neg. cycles, do the following:

- Build a graph, based on a adjacency matrix
- init the values of the matrix with the `log(weight of edge) * (-1)`

This [value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-log(x)) will become positive, if the original value is smaller than 1, or in other words: It is negative for all values greater than 1.

Since `log(m * n) = log(m) * log(n)`, we do not have to multiply anymore to get the result, but simply add the logs.

Therefore, if the algorithm found a negative cycle, we can know that the products it`s edges from the original cycle is greater than 1.